# vue3 i18n, how to combine Vue Router + i18n?

Tags: internationalization, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I would like to combine i18n with the Vue Router (vue3). I can setup the i18n module successfully but the integration into the routing system always fails.

The router-view is located in App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Content here -->
   <the-header></the-header>

   <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
 </template>

<script>
  import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue'

 export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  TheHeader
   }
 }
</script>
```

I access the language routes via a global object $t. The languager switcher works. So the following router-links in the TheHeader component contain the right paths to the language specific components (this.$i18n.locale always returns the right path-fragment: eg: 'en','de' etc.., this works!!):

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" 
          :to="`/${this.$i18n.locale}/home`">{{ $t('nav.home') }}</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link" :to="`/${this.$i18n.locale}/about`">{{ $t(`nav.about`) }} 
       </router-link>
      </li>
```

Now I stuck with the router. I found the following example here, but it does not work:

```
const router = createRouter({
 history: createWebHistory(),

  routes: [
    {
     path: "/:lang",
     component: {
     render: (h) => h("router-view"),
    },
     children: [
     {
      path: "home",
      name: "home",
      component: Home,
     },
     {
      path: "design",
      name: "design",
      component: Design,
    },
    {
      path: "about",
      name: "about",
      component: About,
    },
    {
      path: "contact",
      name: "contact",
      component: Contact,
    },
  ],
},
 ],
});
```

stack trace:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: h is not a function
at Proxy.render (router.js?41cb:15)
at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:464)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4332)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4458)
at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4241)
at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4199)
at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3791)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4409)
at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
```

Principally, the language switcher should work independently from the router, with the independent global variable $t. However, I need the complete path in the URL, I need an integration of i18n into the router! How can I configure the Vue Router correctly?

Comment: I made a big leap forward. My router-link liks like this: <router-link  :to=" {name: 'home', params:{lang: this.$i18n.locale}}">{{ $t('nav.home') }}</router-link>, my  routes config like this:  {
      path: "/:lang/home",
      name: "home",
      component: Home,
    }.   Now I still need to fix the first render of the pages, let's say when I open: /es/design, that does not work right now. Can I use navigation guards?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { h, resolveComponent } from "vue";

path: "/:lang",
component: {
  render() {
    return h(resolveComponent("router-view"));
  },
},
```